# Set border radius of div from input form

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a square div that i wan to change it's border radius based on a text input.
eg.The user types this 4 values in a form:25px 90em 87px 9m.I want when the user clicks the submit button to save that text and then use it as a border radius
I have this html:

```
<div id="radius"></div>
```

this css:

```
#radius{
   hight:10em;width:10em;
   background:aqua;
}
```

and this form:

```
 <input type="text" id="userSet"/>
     <button onclick="$('#radius').css($('#userSet').val())">Submit></button>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Not clear what you want and what your code does

Comment: Your jQuery is Invalid and your Markup is also '</radius>' ?

Comment: just copy paste typo

Comment: I didn't mean to criticize them

Comment: Among your other typos already mentioned you also have a typo in your css, hight should be height

Comment: sorry but don't worry I was typing fast this is why i missed the "e"

Comment: No problem. This just a friendly advice: if you expect other to spend time on solving your programming problems/exercises you will get better response if you are more precise in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try this

```
<button onclick="$('#radius').css($('#userSet').val())">Submit></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to set **border radius**,try this :

```
 <input type="text" id="userSet"/><button onclick="$('#radius').css('border-radius', $('#userSet').val())">Submit></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors i fix them in your html:

```
<div id="radius"></div>
<input type="text" id="userSet"/>
<button onclick="$('#radius').css('border-radius', parseInt($('#userSet').val()));">Submit></button>
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e99s9jq9/8/)

You have to use border-radius and use parseInt.

> The border-radius property is a shorthand property for setting the
>   four border-*-radius properties.

Comment: what is parseInt(Sorry if it was a stupid question but I am new to javascript)

Comment: @ManosKounelakis The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<button onClick="$('#radius').css('border-radius', $('#userSet').val() + 'px');">Submit></button>
```

See [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aq168nwy/) here

Comment: `radius` is not a valid CSS property.

Comment: also i don't want to use px.I want to let the user free to choose what value he prefers(px cm in % em pt)

Comment: That was not clear from your original question, please dont change the question after people have answered

Comment: I am sorry I had to write it